# Populating values in dropdowns

Tags: javascript

I need to create dropdowns using javascript/jquery

Values in the first dropdown should be as follows:

```
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">Occ1</option>
<option value="2">Occ2</option>
```

Second dropdown should be shown only if the value selected from the first dropdown is other Select

```
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="11">subOcc1</option>
<option value="12">subOcc2</option>
```

Third dropdown should be shown only if the value selected from the second dropdown is other than Select

```
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="111">superSubOcc1</option>
<option value="112">superSubOcc2</option>
<option value="113">superSubOcc3</option>
<option value="114">superSubOcc4</option>
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this works for you.

**HTML**

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="0">select</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="select2">
    <option value="0">select</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="select3">
    <option value="0">select</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
for (var key in data) {
    $("#select1").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + data[key].name + '</option>');
}

$("#select1").change(function () {
    $('#select2').find('option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() != '0';
    }).remove();

    $('#select3').find('option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() != '0';
    }).remove();

    var currentSelect = $(this).val();
    var currentOccupation = data[currentSelect].occupation;
    for (var key in currentOccupation) {
        $("#select2").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + currentOccupation[key].name + '</option>');
    }

});


$("#select2").change(function () {
    $('#select3').find('option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() != '0';
    }).remove();

    var currentSelect1 = $("#select1").val();
    var currentSelect2 = $(this).val();
    var currentOccupation = data[currentSelect1].occupation[currentSelect2].occupation;

    for (var key in currentOccupation) {
        $("#select3").append('<option value="' + currentOccupation[key].occCode + '">' + currentOccupation[key].name + '</option>');
    }

});
```